# Why the expr parser only can parse the first item of it?

Tags: scala, parsing, parser-combinators

I have a Praser

```scala
package app
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._


class MyParser extends JavaTokenParsers {
  import MyParser._
  
  def expr =
    plus | sub | multi | divide | num
  
  def num = floatingPointNumber ^^ (x => Value(x.toDouble).e)

  def plus = num ~ rep("+" ~> num) ^^ {
    case num ~ nums => nums.foldLeft(num.e) {
      (x, y) => Operation("+", x, y)
    }
  }

  def sub = num ~ rep("-" ~> num) ^^ {
    case num ~ nums => nums.foldLeft(num.e){
      (x, y) => Operation("-", x, y)
    }
  }

  def multi = num ~ rep("*" ~> num) ^^ {
    case num ~ nums => nums.foldLeft(num.e){
      (x, y) => Operation("*", x, y)
    }
  }

  def divide = num ~ rep("/" ~> num) ^^ {
    case num ~ nums => nums.foldLeft(num.e){
      (x, y) => Operation("/", x, y)
    }
  }
}

object MyParser {
  sealed trait Expr {
    def e = this.asInstanceOf[Expr]
    def compute: Double = this match {
      case Value(x) => x
      case Operation(op, left, right) => (op : @unchecked) match {
        case "+" => left.compute + right.compute
        case "-" => left.compute - right.compute
        case "*" => left.compute * right.compute
        case "/" => left.compute / right.compute
      }
    }
  }

  case class Value(x: Double) extends Expr
  case class Operation(op: String, left: Expr, right: Expr) extends Expr
}
```

and I use it to parse the expression something

```scala
package app

object Runner extends App {
  val p = new MyParser
  println(p.parseAll(p.expr, "1 * 11"))
}
```

it prints

```
[1.3] failure: end of input expected

1 * 11
  ^
```

but if I parse the expression `1 + 11`, it will succeed in parsing it.

```
[1.7] parsed: Operation(+,Value(1.0),Value(11.0))
```

and I can parse something through the `plus` , `multi` , `divide` , `num` , `sub` combinator , but the `expr` combinator only can parse the first item of the or combinator .
so why it only can parse the first item of the `expr` parser? And how can I change the definition of the parsers to make the parse successful ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using `rep` which matches zero or more times.

```scala
def rep[T](p: => Parser[T]): Parser[List[T]] = rep1(p) | success(List())
```

you need to use `rep1` instead which would require at least one match.

If you replace all `rep` with `rep1`, your code works.

Check out the changes on [scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/lJF7PqFlT12BaQqcpoQAPA)

Answer (score 0):

Run an experiment:

```
println(p.parseAll(p.expr, "1 + 11"))
println(p.parseAll(p.expr, "1 - 11"))
println(p.parseAll(p.expr, "1 * 11"))
println(p.parseAll(p.expr, "1 / 11"))
```

What will happen?

```
[1.7] parsed: Operation(+,Value(1.0),Value(11.0))
[1.3] failure: end of input expected
1 - 11
  ^
[1.3] failure: end of input expected
1 * 11
  ^
[1.3] failure: end of input expected
1 / 11
```

`+` is consumed, but everything else fails. Let's change `def expr` definition

```
  def expr =
    multi | plus | sub | divide | num
```

```
[1.3] failure: end of input expected
1 + 11
  ^
[1.3] failure: end of input expected
1 - 11
  ^
[1.7] parsed: Operation(*,Value(1.0),Value(11.0))
[1.3] failure: end of input expected
1 / 11
  ^
```

By moving `multi` to the beginning, `*` case passed, but `+` failed.

```
  def expr =
    num | multi | plus | sub | divide
```

```
[1.3] failure: end of input expected
1 + 11
  ^
[1.3] failure: end of input expected
1 - 11
  ^
[1.3] failure: end of input expected
1 * 11
  ^
[1.3] failure: end of input expected
1 / 11
```

With `num` as the first case everything fails. It is apparent now that this code

```
num | multi | plus | sub | divide
```

is NOT matching if any of its parts match, but only if the first one matches.

What does docs says about it?

```
   /** A parser combinator for alternative composition.
     *
     *  `p | q` succeeds if `p` succeeds or `q` succeeds.
     *   Note that `q` is only tried if `p`s failure is non-fatal (i.e., back-tracking is allowed).
     *
     * @param q a parser that will be executed if `p` (this parser) fails (and allows back-tracking)
     * @return a `Parser` that returns the result of the first parser to succeed (out of `p` and `q`)
     *         The resulting parser succeeds if (and only if)
     *         - `p` succeeds, ''or''
     *         - if `p` fails allowing back-tracking and `q` succeeds.
     */
  def | [U >: T](q: => Parser[U]): Parser[U] = append(q).named("|")
```

Important note: back tracking has to be allowed. If it isn't, then failure to match the first parser, will results in failing the alternative without trying the second parser at all.

How to make your parser backtracking? Well, you would have to use [`PackratParsers`](https://github.com/scala/scala-parser-combinators/blob/8b011a5a52d5a61828b7979f4b12752fbcbd5d14/shared/src/main/scala/scala/util/parsing/combinator/PackratParsers.scala) as this is the only parser in the library that supports backtracking. Or rewrite your code to not rely on backtracking in the first place.

Personally, I recommend not using Scala Parser Combinators and instead use a library where you explicitly decide when you can still backtrack, and when you should not allow it, like e.g. [fastparse](http://www.lihaoyi.com/fastparse/).